# How to prevent Django from auto converting datetime

Tags: django, django-templates, python-datetime

Datetime value such as, `day = "2017-9-2 00:00:00"` ,

when used in template,

index.html

```
...

{{day}} 
...
```

it is auto converted by Django to `Sept. 2, 2017, midnight`.

How can I disable this behavior?

I want it to display in its original format, `"2017-9-2 00:00:00"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should override [`settings.DATETIME_FORMAT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#datetime-format) in your settings in order to override the default format.

`settings.py`:

```
# ...

USE_L10N = False                 # At first, disable USE_L10N, because it overrides the format
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'  # Set your own datetime format
```

Now every `datetime` in your project should be present in this format.

**EDIT**: If you don't want to globally format all the dates in this format, you can specifically format this date in your template, like this:

```
{{ day|date:'Y-m-d H:i:s' }}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! A little edit was needed, though. `DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'`

Comment: @upoque Oh, I've mistyped this. I will edit my answer now. Make sure to accept it if it helped you. :)

Comment: I'm a newb to the third power (new to Python, Django, and Javascript, oh and programming) and tore my hair out the last three days until I found this first answer from #wencakisa. #Wencakisa's second answer is the more commonplace one but I couldn't use it because I was sorting the dates in javascript BEFORE rednering, which of course means it was putting February before Januar (for example). #Wencakis's first answer, about changing it globally in settings, did the job for me.

Comment: @geekandglitter I'm happy that my answer helped. Keep goin' ! :)